# Problem with NSFetchedResultsController and inserting records

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Ok, this one is driving me crazy and I've tried everything I can find on the internet as a possible solution but still nothing.  So here is my situation:
I have a view that has a button on it.  When this is touched it pops up a list of customers for the user to select from.  when they select it, i make a use the fetchedresultscontroller to get the parts associated to the customer and display them in a tableview.  This all works well.  the problem is if I have Customer A selected and insert a new part, then go to Customer B and insert a new part, when i reselect Customer A and try to insert another part the app crashes with the following error:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1447.6.4/UITableView.m:976
>   2011-02-21 10:39:12.896
>   SalesPro[36203:207] Serious
>   application error.  An exception was
>   caught from the delegate of
>   NSFetchedResultsController during a
>   call to -controllerDidChangeContent:. 
>   Invalid update: invalid number of rows
>   in section 0.  The number of rows
>   contained in an existing section after
>   the update (1) must be equal to the
>   number of rows contained in that
>   section before the update (1), plus or
>   minus the number of rows inserted or
>   deleted from that section (1 inserted,
>   0 deleted). with userInfo (null)
>   2011-02-21 10:39:12.907
>   SalesPro[36203:207] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '-[UITableView
>   scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]:
>   row (1) beyond bounds (1) for section
>   (0).'

**Code that handles selecting of Customer**

```
-(void) CustomerSelectedRaised:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    NSLog(@"Received Notification - Customer Selected");
    selectedCustomer = (Customer *)[notif object];
    [self buildCustomerInfoText];
    if (popoverController != nil) {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }

    fetchedResultsController = nil;

    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        //Update to handle error appropriately
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1); //fail
    }

    [self.partsListGrid reloadData];
}
```

**FetchedResultsController code**

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fetch results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    //set-up fetched results controller
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PartsList" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    NSLog(@"TAMS ID: %@", selectedCustomer.customerTAMSID);
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"customerTAMSID == %@", selectedCustomer.customerTAMSID]]; 

    //set to sort by customer name
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sortOrder" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];   
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
                                                             initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                             managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext] 
                                                             sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    [aFetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];
    [self setFetchedResultsController:aFetchedResultsController];

    //clean-up
    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    //return results
    return fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller 
{
    [[self partsListGrid] beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // In the simplest, most efficient, case, reload the table view.
    [[self partsListGrid] endUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.partsListGrid;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath withHeight:tableView.rowHeight];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.partsListGrid insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.partsListGrid deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: 
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**Add Part code**

```
-(void) addScannedPart:(Part *)part 
{
    // Check to see if entered part is already in list
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *partsEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PartsList" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:partsEntity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"customerTAMSID == %@ AND lineAbbreviation == %@ AND partNumber == %@", selectedCustomer.customerTAMSID, part.lineAbbrev, part.partNumber];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedParts = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if ([fetchedParts count] == 0) {
        //Create a new instance of the entity managed object by the fetched results controller
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [[fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];

        NSLog(@"Entity Name: %@", [entity name]);

        NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

        //Add fields to Managed Object
        int sortOrder = [[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count];
        sortOrder++;

        [newManagedObject setValue:[part lineAbbrev] forKey:@"lineAbbreviation"];
        [newManagedObject setValue:[part partNumber] forKey:@"partNumber"];
        [newManagedObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[part orderQty] intValue]] forKey:@"orderQuantity"];
        [newManagedObject setValue:selectedCustomer.customerTAMSID forKey:@"customerTAMSID"];
        [newManagedObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sortOrder] forKey:@"sortOrder"];

        //Save the context
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }

        //reload Customer list 
        NSIndexPath *insertionPath = [fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:newManagedObject];
        [self.partsListGrid selectRowAtIndexPath:insertionPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
        [self.partsListGrid reloadData];
    }
}
```

This is the biggest (most severe) defect I have to figure out for our next release (which is very soon).  I'd appreciate any and all help!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, thanks to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494095/how-to-switch-uitableviews-nsfetchedresultscontroller-or-its-predicate-program), it looks like I have it working:

I edited by CustomerSelectedRaised method to look like so:

```
-(void) CustomerSelectedRaised:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    NSLog(@"Received Notification - Customer Selected");
    selectedCustomer = (Customer *)[notif object];
    [self buildCustomerInfoText];
    if (popoverController != nil) {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    //this is the new code
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[self fetchedResultsController] fetchRequest];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = nil;
    entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PartsList" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"customerTAMSID == %@", selectedCustomer.customerTAMSID]]; 

    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:nil];
    // end of new code

    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        //Update to handle error appropriately
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1); //fail
    }

    [self.partsListGrid reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

start with fixing the leaking NSFetchedResultsCOntroller in

```
-(void) CustomerSelectedRaised:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    /*...*/
    fetchedResultsController = nil;
    /*...*/
}
```

you shouldn't have multiple NSFetchedResultsControllers that all report changes to the same tableview. And I think this is what is happening. Unless the NSFRController gets deallocated it will report changes to its delegate

Comment: yes, thanks.  if you look at my answer to my own question, I had removed that.  I'm a .NET developer, still learning Objective-C and iPhone development, and it's the memory management that's tripping me up the most, but I'm getting the hang of it.