# Recipes for changing the Fetch Request for NSFetchedResultsController and reloading table data

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest, reloaddata

From apple doc [Modifying the Fetch Request](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) I see that is possible to change the `NSFetchRequest` for `NSFetchedResultsController`. Steps are easy to set up.

After invoking `performFetch:` I think there is the need to call `reloadData` on the the table view. How to perform such call?

Reading some stackoverflow topics, I've seen that calling that method should work in most cases. But is there a right way to do it?

In [How to switch UITableView's NSFetchedResultsController (or its predicate) programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494095/how-to-switch-uitableviews-nsfetchedresultscontroller-or-its-predicate-progra), **TechZen** wrote that:

> Just make sure to send the tableview itself a beginUpdates before you
>   swap controllers and then an endUpdates when you are done. This
>   prevents the table from asking for data in the narrow window when the
>   FRC are being swapped out. Then call reloadData.

Could you explain exactly what does it mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that the logic to generate the correct fetch (some kind of conditional statement) is in the getter of your NSFetchedResultsController instance. Then it is really easy

```
self.fetchedResultsController = nil; // this destroys the old one
[self.tableview reloadData]; 
// when the table view is reloaded the fetchedResultsController will be lazily recreated
```

Edit: adding complete code sample of something I've done. Basically I have a NSDictionary entityDescription that hold values to customize the creation of a NSFetchedResultsController. If I want to change the fetchRequest I change my entityDescription variable to indicate the new values and override the setter to reset the fetchedResultsController and reload the table. It gives you the basic idea.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController 
{
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }
    if (self.entityDescription == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    // Set up the fetched results controller.
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[self.entityDescription objectForKey:kEntityName]];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    if ([[self.entityDescription objectForKey:kEntitySortField] isEqualToString:@"null"] == NO) {
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:[self.entityDescription objectForKey:kEntitySortField] ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    }

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                                                                managedObjectContext:self.moc sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return __fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)setEntityDescription:(NSDictionary *)entityDescription
{
    _entityDescription = entityDescription;
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you explain better what do you mean? Cheers.